# Validating textarea PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="post">
   <textarea name="TextArea" required  placeholder="Write Something..." id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Ask"/>
</form>
```

I want to validate this form and when user writes something then It should take that text to another page for example article.php and users can read that text.

Comment: Use `strlen` function

Comment: Your question is too broad; try something first. You won't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (strlen($_POST["TextArea"]) > 0) {
    header("Location: article.php?data=".$_POST["TextArea"]);
}
?>
```

You can try this code. If textarea contains more then `0` character it will be redirected to `article.php` with the textarea data.

Now you have to use this code to get the `textarea data` in `article.php`.

```
<?php
$data=$_GET["data"];
echo $data;
?>
```

If `textarea` data is related to `MYSQL` you have to change the system of getting `textarea data` to prevent `MYSQL Injection`.

Comment: Bear in mind with a redirect using `header` the details of the submitted form will not be passed on to the next page

Comment: Thanks @andrewsi.. Updated :)

Comment: plus, article.php would need to grab that GET in "data"

Answer (score 1):

Using `POST` is *adviced*:

**article.php**

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="TextArea" required  placeholder="Write Something..." id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button name="querysubmit" type="submit">ASK</button>
</form>
```

**validate.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["querysubmit"]))
{
    $txt=$_POST["TextArea"];
    //Do your validation here :)
}
else{header("location:article.php?err=1");}
?>
```

Comment: forms do not hold the name attribute and therefore the name attribute should be set for the button.